# Store 8 Ascii Values in unsigned int

Tags: c, hex, ascii

I have a query. I have a string of ascii value . which i am reading from Hex file. consider the string is "0004EB9C" . which is copied in unsigned char buffer.

```
unsigned char buff[8] = {'0','0','0','4','E','B','9','C'}
unsigned int j = 0;
```

Now this string or information has to be transmitted through UART communication. consider this represents my RAM address for Execution. I need to store this 8 byte ascii value in in an unsigned int . I am not finding a way can some one please focus on this.
the output after copying/converting this string should be like

```
printf("%x",j);
```

this should print

```
Output : 0x0004EB9C
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

```
set answer to 0
for each character
   left-shift answer by 4
   if the character is between '0' and '9' inclusive
       subtract '0' from it
   else
       subtract 'A' from it and add 10
   bitwise-or this into answer
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char data[] =  "0004EB59C";
    const int len = sizeof(data)/sizeof(char)-1;
    int i,value[sizeof(data)/sizeof(char)-1];
 unsigned int j = 0;
   
    for(i=0;i<len;++i)
{
    j <<= 4;
    printf("%d\t",i); 
       printf("0x%x\n", value[i]);
  if(value[i] >= '0' && value[i] <= '9')
  {
   value[i] = value[i] - '0';
  } 
  else
  {
   value[i] = (value[i] - 'A') + 10;
  }
    j |=  value[i];

}
printf("%x",j);
    return 0;
}

Please confirm.. this doesnt work

Comment: I see no purpose to your `value` array, which, by the way, you don't initialize (it has arbitrary data in it). Just use the `data` array, perhaps copying each char to a temporary for the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char data[] =  "004EB59C";
    const int len = sizeof(data)/sizeof(char)-1;

    int i,value[sizeof(data)/sizeof(char)-1];
    unsigned int j = 0;

    for(i=0;i<len;++i)
        sscanf(data+i, "%1x",value + i);

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
       j <<= 4;
       j |= (0x0f & value[i]);             
       printf("%x\n",j);    
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Corrected Code. I would request to improvise this answer if possible.

Comment: Why not just `sscanf(data, "%x", &j);`

Comment: Hi !!.. ooga.. can u improvise this.. actually i want to write a code to read a complete ascii file and copy it into a buffer after processing . can you improvise this..

Answer (score 0):

To store as `unsigned j`

```
unsigned char buff[8] = {'0','0','0','4','E','B','9','C'}
unsigned char buff2[sizeof buff + 1];
memcpy(buff2, buff, sizeof buff);
buff2[sizeof buff] = '\0';
unsigned int j = (unsigned) strtoul(buff2, 0, 16);
```

To print via `j`

```
printf("%#08x",j);
```

To print via directly via `buff`

```
fputs("0x", stdout);
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof buff; i++)
  fputc(tolower(buff[i]), stdout);
```